# K modes cluster sampling

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, sampling

I would like to sample my clusters after applying k modes to my dataset. I have build the following code so far:

```
 import numpy as np
 from kmodes import kmodes

 X = df[cols].astype(str)
 km = kmodes.KModes(n_clusters=10)
 clusters = km.fit_predict(X) 
 df['clusters'] = clusters
```

Now I would like to sample observations from each cluster based on how closest it is from the cluster_centroids. How can I do that?